# How do I find the x and y values in unity

Tags: unityscript

How do I find the x and y values in unity c#

[image]

Comment: Please include more details of your issue with examples.  A link can change or be deleted and your question becomes much harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Take the vector going from object 1 to object 2

```
Vector3 dir = object2.transform.position - object1.transform.position;
```

dir.x, dir.y will be the values you are after